# Change ID in File

Tags: java, file, text, path, rename

Let's say I have this notepad file
name: Company_XXX_768_JGH.txt
Contents:

```
Random Text

Blah Blah Blah

Network ID: 80801568
```

I need to change the ID last 4 numbers (1568) to (0003).

So far I am able to read the whole, find the line with the number AND print a statement for that line. Now I need to replace the last 4 numbers with a new one.

So far I got this:

-------------------------------After JP's Answer------------------------------

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class test {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

        File TEMP = new File("C:\\Users\\Controlled\\Documents\\Company\\E_20150512_101105_0002_80802221_SSH.xml");
        boolean fileExists = TEMP.exists();
        System.out.println(fileExists);
        // The name of the file to open.

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;

        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(TEMP);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            List<String> NewTextFile = new ArrayList<String>();

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(line);
                boolean containsSSH = line.contains("80802221");
                if (containsSSH == true)
                {
                String correctedLine = line.replace("2221","0003");
                    NewTextFile.add(correctedLine);
                    System.out.println(correctedLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    NewTextFile.add(line);
                }

            }    
            bufferedReader.close();
            // Always close files.
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Controlled\\Documents\\Company\\Test.xml");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());

            // if file doesn't exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
            bw.write(line); // How to write a List to a file?
            bw.close();

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                TEMP + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + TEMP + "'");                   
            // Or we could just do this: 
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store each of the line you read in a list (an ArrayList or a LinkedList, doesn't matter). Store the line as is, except if containsSSH is true, in which case you store `line.replace("1568","0003)` (the string is returned by the replace call).
Then close your reader, open a BufferedWriter, and write back the lines in the same order, not forgetting to call newLine() between each. Voila!

Comment: So I updated my code. For some reason the writing isnt working.

Comment: Make sure you close the reader before opening the writer, and add your new code to your question or open a new question!

Comment: So I now have a List. I need to write that to a file correct? Is that a for loop?

Comment: for (String l:NewTextFile){bw.write(l);bw.newLine();}

Comment: GOT IT! Thanks a bunch man. I learned a lot with this program.